# Change comparison function to sort draws according to second entry of a paired vector

Tags: c++, c++11

This is part of a larger code, but the following should give a precise enough idea. Consider the following code to sorting many a `<int,double>` pairs according to their second entry:

```
using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;
using Eigen::VectorXd;
using Eigen::VectorXi;

class SortData {
public:
    int index;
    double value;
    SortData();
    SortData(int,double);
};
inline SortData::SortData(int first,double second) {
    index=first;
    value=second;
}
bool sortDataIsLess(const SortData& left,const SortData& right){
    return left.value<right.value;
}
```

[...]

```
const int n=x.size();
vector<SortData> VectortoSort(n);
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)     VectortoSort[i]=SortData(i,x(i));
std::sort(VectortoSort.begin(),VectortoSort.begin()+n,sortDataIsLess);
```

[...]

My question is: how can I change the sorting operator `sortDataIsLess()` so that 
the draws in `VectortoSort()` are sorted according to its first entry (which, by construction contains no draws)?

Comment: Why do you pass the constructor parameters by reference, and why is the constness different?

Comment: thanks, you are right about the constness: I'll fix this now.  The pass by ref is how I usually see it done in Eigen c++, but maybe I don't understand your question: what function are you talking about?

Comment: SortData could be `SortData(const int& first, const double& second)` or `SortData(int first, double second)`. Basic data types can be passed by value as they are small.

Comment: @NeilKirk: ok, can you check that I didn't introduce any mistakes by doing as you suggest? I'm not too sure about my current sortDataIsLess()...[sorry i'm learning]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bool sortDataIsLess(const SortData& left,const SortData& right){
    if(left.value == right.value)
        return left.index < right.index;
    return left.value<right.value;
}
```

Should do the trick.

Edit: Note that SortData.value is a double. Comparing floating point numbers with `==` may lead to false results. You may want to use a specific evaluation fuction:

```
bool sortDataIsLess(const SortData& left,const SortData& right){
    if(equalsD(left.value, right.value))
        return left.index < right.index;
    return left.value<right.value;
}

bool equalsD(double l, double r) {
    return (abs(l-r) < EPSILON)); // EPSILON is the tolerance to be used
}
```

Comment: isn't it more correct to replace '==' by abs(left.value-right.value)<tol?

Comment: You're right, since we compare floating point numbers we should use a specific evaluation function.

Comment: Just finished doing so :)

Comment: Your second method is not correct. You don't necessary get transitivity of orders. It is a requirement of a comparison that if x < y and y < z then x < z. But that may fail. E.g. take x = (0.0, 0), y = (-2.0*EPSILON/3.0, 1) and z = (-4.0*EPSILON/3.0, 2). Here x < y and y < z, but z < x.

Comment: Well, I have to admit that I yet didn't have to deal with these usecases where your floating point comparison has to be accurate to the 20th digit. The code sample above should do the deal for the OP's problem. However, if you have a code sample which covers all eventualities, I'll edit it in.

Comment: @Nimelrian it's not about "accurate to the 20th digit". It's about the function not being a valid comparison to pass to `sort`. It's not inaccuracies this causes, it's undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Nimelrian Your first method is fine. There is no problem sorting floating-point numbers. Their internal format do form a Strict Weak Ordering.

Comment: I also don't like the sentence "Comparing floating point numbers with == may lead to false results." because it is, at best, misleading, and at worst, wrong. Comparing floating point numbers with `==` doesn't give "false results" and it is never inaccurate. It is always perfectly exact.

Comment: @user515430 It could get problematic though to compare using `==` to determine whether we go and evaluate the second value (`index`, in this case) or not.

-=-=-

@R.MartinhoFernandes In how far is the first function no valid sort-evaluation? `std::sort()` will put the smaller (value, if equal, index) entry first, the greater therafter.